# Store C++0x lambda-functions in a std::map/vector for later use in Visual Studio

Tags: lambda, c++11

Im working on a small graphics engine project that and I want to it to be crossed platform (someday). I been developing with latest version of MinGW and C++0x.
For event listeners I use lambda functions stored in a std::map that will be called when a certain event occurs. It works really smooth with MinGW but the other day when I tried it in Visual Studio (latest version) it failed.

I inspected the type of the lambdas and even if I define two lambdas to be excatly the same, they get different types (annonymous namespace:: and annonymous namespace::)).

For example i have this std::map to store scroll listeners

```
std::map<int,void (*)(int p)> scrollListenerFunctions;
```

And then I can add a listener by just do:

```
addScrollListener([](int p){/* Do something here */});
```

As I said, this works fine in MinGW but fails in Visual Studio, is there a way of doing it so it works in both and is it even possible to store lambdas in VS atm?

If you wnat/need to see more code you can find it here http://code.google.com/p/aotk/source/browse/ the lambda maps are located in window.h / window.cpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of this:

```
std::map<int,void (*)(int p)> scrollListenerFunctions;
```

you must have this:

```
std::map<int,std::function<void(int p)> > scrollListenerFunctions;
```

The thing is that a lambda is not convertible to a function-pointer. You need a more generic callback wrapper, like `std::function`

Answer (score 5):

Stateless lambdas can convert to function pointers but Visual Studio does not yet support it, it was added after they implemented lambdas. You really should be using `std::function` anyway.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Is that in the final draft? I thought that a lambda is equivalent to a struct with operator () in it. I guess I was wrong :)

Comment: @Armen: Yes, the most recent C++0x spec has the ability to have lambda functions that capture _nothing_ be equivalent to a function pointer. This was added when VC2010 was nearly finished, so it didn't implement it.

Comment: @Armen: It is, basically. But for stateless lambdas, then there's no reason that they can't be equivalent to a free function.